# UIWebView not able to play sound when hitting it with game url

Tags: uiwebview, avaudiosession

Both Safari and Chrome on iPhone can play the backend sound when visit this webpage. However, when use UIWebView to visit it, there is no backend sound. There must be some special setting to make it work.

Tried many online solutions, such as, but still not working.Please help me out.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];


_webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
_webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and it works for me
hope so it will also work for u

```
-(void)loadWebView:(UIWebView *)webView withUrl:(NSString *)urlString
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL ok;
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    ok = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                             error:&setCategoryError];
    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"setCategoryError=%@", setCategoryError);
    }

    webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

    NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
    NSString *encodedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:characterSet];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString]]];
}
```